# SQL Query which depends on the existence of other rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table structure (and data example):

```
id  code category
1   x    c1    
1   y    c1    
1   a    c2
2   y    c1
2   a    c2
3   a    c2
4   j    c3
```

Given a list of pairs <(category, code)>, one for each category, I need to query the `ids` which match the pairs. The rule is: if a category is present for the `id`, its pair must be in the list for the `id` to be returned.

For example, if the input pairs are (c1, x), (c2, a), (c3, k) the `ids` to be returned are: 1 and 3.

2 must not be returned, because the `c1` category does not match the code `x`.
3 is returned because for the only category present, the code matches `a`.

I've tried using `(EXISTS(c1 and code) or NOT EXISTS(c1)) AND (EXISTS(c2 and code) or NOT EXISTS(c2)) AND...` but could not eliminate `id=2` from the results.

Comment: will the input pairs be passed to the query dynamically?

Comment: @vkp yes. There will always be a fixed number of pairs (=the number of categories).

Comment: in case of same code and category combination with a different id, what should be returned?

Comment: @vkp Sorry, what do you mean? The id does not come from the input.

Comment: how are the pairs passed? technically speaking?

Comment: @Sebas The pairs come in the form of `Map<category, code>`

Comment: But, you build the query dynamically from java?

Comment: @Sebas Yes, from Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like here:

```
with input(cat, code) as (select 'c1', 'x' from dual 
                union all select 'c2', 'a' from dual
                union all select 'c3', 'k' from dual)
select id from (
  select t.id, max(decode(i.code, t.code, 1, 0)) cc from t
    left join input i on i.cat = t.cat and i.code = t.code
    group by t.id, t.cat)
  group by id having min(cc) = 1;
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/af712/1)</sup>

This way you don't have to write all these new `not exist... or exists...` clauses, and data is hit only once (important from performance point of view).

Comment: Thanks. Why do you fetch from `dual` and not from `t` ?

Comment: You are welcome. Subquery `input` is a kind of simple table built ad hoc, it only stores parameters in form of table which 
is next joined with `t` - so "real" selection is from `t` by this join. And by using `with ...` we don't have to repeat this values.

Answer (score 1):

Made it work with the following query:

```
select distinct t2.ID from t t2
where
( not exists (select * from t where id = t2.id and cat like 'c2') 
or (exists ( select * from t where id = t2.id and cat = 'c2' and code = 'a')))
and
(not exists (select * from t where id = t2.id and cat like 'c1') 
or (exists( select * from t where id = t2.id and cat = 'c1' and code = 'x')))
and
(not exists (select * from t where id = t2.id and cat like 'c3') 
or (exists( select * from t where id = t2.id and cat = 'c3' and code = 'k')))
; </pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can stuff your (category, code) pairs into something table-like, you could just join and group by id.

```
SELECT id
FROM table
JOIN ( 
    SELECT category1, code1
    UNION SELECT category2, code2
    ...
) 
ON table.category = pairs.category AND table.code = pairs.code
GROUP BY id
```